# Condition check based on Pandas rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

Based on the reproducable code below I have the following dataframe:

```
df.tail(10)

             open   high    low       close   200MA       20MA    Trend
date                            
2020-12-24  1.3273  1.3384  1.3257  1.3384  1.324826    1.325365    Up
2020-12-25  1.3408  1.3408  1.3268  1.3268  1.324926    1.326240    Up
2020-12-26  1.3268  1.3283  1.3217  1.3239  1.325008    1.326085    Up
2020-12-27  1.3240  1.3240  1.3078  1.3078  1.325009    1.325215    Up
2020-12-28  1.3103  1.3103  1.2878  1.2878  1.324973    1.323490    Down
2020-12-29  1.2893  1.2932  1.2876  1.2886  1.324951    1.321890    Down
2020-12-30  1.2871  1.2937  1.2810  1.2906  1.324923    1.319755    Down
2020-12-31  1.2905  1.3020  1.2905  1.2993  1.324934    1.318450    Down
2021-01-01  1.3006  1.3022  1.2896  1.2905  1.324893    1.316830    Down
2021-01-02  1.2909  1.3085  1.2890  1.3008  1.324908    1.315660    Down
```

I want a new column based on the following conditions:

- For each row look back over a rolling window of 20 periods
- If during the last 20 periods there are rows where df['20MA'] > df['200MA'] &
- If during the last 20 periods there are also rows were df['20MA'] < df['200MA']

**Desired output:**

- Add the value "Neutral" to a new column named "Trend 20 Window" if the conditions are met.

I have tried using the rolling window functionality in Pandas but struggled to get the required results.

**Code to reproduce the example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def genMockDataFrame(days,startPrice,colName,startDate,seed=None): 
   
    periods = days*24
    np.random.seed(seed)
    steps = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=0.0018, size=periods)
    steps[0]=0
    P = startPrice+np.cumsum(steps)
    P = [round(i,4) for i in P]

    fxDF = pd.DataFrame({ 
        'ticker':np.repeat( [colName], periods ),
        'date':np.tile( pd.date_range(startDate, periods=periods, freq='H'), 1 ),
        'price':(P)})
    fxDF.index = pd.to_datetime(fxDF.date)
    fxDF = fxDF.price.resample('D').ohlc()
    return fxDF

df = genMockDataFrame(290,1.1904,'eurusd','19/3/2020',seed=1)

df["200MA"] = df["close"].rolling(window=200).mean()
df["20MA"] = df["close"].rolling(window=20).mean()
df.loc[df['20MA'] > df['200MA'], "Trend"] = "Up"
df.loc[df['20MA'] < df['200MA'], "Trend"] = "Down"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean mask created by comparing `df['20MA']` with `df['200MA']` using `.gt()` and `.lt()` and check the results within rolling window with `.rolling()` by checking `.sum()` of number of rows fulfilling condition within rolling windows being >=1 with `.ge(1)`.  Then use `.loc()` on the mask to assign 'Neutral' to new column for the matching rows, as follows:

```
df['Trend 20 Window'] = ''        # init to ''
periods = 20
mask = df['20MA'].gt(df['200MA']).rolling(periods).sum().ge(1) & df['20MA'].lt(df['200MA']).rolling(periods).sum().ge(1)
df.loc[mask, 'Trend 20 Window'] = 'Neutral'
```

### Demo

Let's **test it with** your sample data (10 rows) with a **smaller rolling window of 3**:

```
df['Trend 20 Window'] = ''
periods = 3
mask = df['20MA'].gt(df['200MA']).rolling(periods).sum().ge(1) & df['20MA'].lt(df['200MA']).rolling(periods).sum().ge(1)
df.loc[mask, 'Trend 20 Window'] = 'Neutral'
```

Result:

```
              open    high     low   close     200MA      20MA Trend Trend 20 Window
date                                                                                
2020-12-24  1.3273  1.3384  1.3257  1.3384  1.324826  1.325365    Up                
2020-12-25  1.3408  1.3408  1.3268  1.3268  1.324926  1.326240    Up                
2020-12-26  1.3268  1.3283  1.3217  1.3239  1.325008  1.326085    Up                
2020-12-27  1.3240  1.3240  1.3078  1.3078  1.325009  1.325215    Up                
2020-12-28  1.3103  1.3103  1.2878  1.2878  1.324973  1.323490  Down         Neutral
2020-12-29  1.2893  1.2932  1.2876  1.2886  1.324951  1.321890  Down         Neutral
2020-12-30  1.2871  1.2937  1.2810  1.2906  1.324923  1.319755  Down                
2020-12-31  1.2905  1.3020  1.2905  1.2993  1.324934  1.318450  Down                
2021-01-01  1.3006  1.3022  1.2896  1.2905  1.324893  1.316830  Down                
2021-01-02  1.2909  1.3085  1.2890  1.3008  1.324908  1.315660  Down
```